# How can I get my character to move?

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

I am unable to move this character around. I have already parented the meshes to the armature, but when I go to pose mode, I am unable to move any part of my character.

[image]

What can I do to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Your file works just fine on my PC.

Comment: It does? I don't get it. I am moving the box and the circle around the head. The mesh is just still.

Comment: The box and the circle are not connected to anything as far as I can tell. Select the armature pocking out of his knees and go into Pose Mode.

Comment: Hmm. that does work, but how can I get the armature to be connected to the box and circle

Comment: I don't have much experience in that area but I would assume parenting the bone to the shape using Ctrl + P